# How can i find domain associated with a specific nameserver?

Tags: dns, hosting, whois, nameservers, registrar

Hi is there any way to find all the domain associated with a specific name server, I have the ip address as well, but i'm getting a result of 600+ domains. I want to narrow down the search to domains that are linked with that particular name server.
Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Not realistically, no. There is no central registry of name servers, and trying to iterate through the entire global DNS tree is not feasible.

Comment: People do it that way: take a list of domain names, query for their NS, store the results. After doing that long enough and for many domains names you can with your local database do the reverse query and get a list of domain names from a given nameserver. Various companies provide that online. Also, if you are a registrar, you get access to some registries reports (depending on registries) which clearly show domain names per nameserver.